# How to refresh on closing dijit.dialog

Tags: dojo, dialog

I'm using dijit.dialog to show the popup dialog. How do I refresh the parent page on closing dijit.Dialog? Please advise. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a listener to the `hide` event, and you need `location.reload()`. It will be a lot easier to answer your question if you post some code and list what you've tried already.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/kXsQ4/) illustrating how to use `location.reload()` when a `dijit/Dialog` closes with Dojo 1.8.

The relevant code:

```
d.on('hide', function() {
    console.log('closed');
    location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as below, you just need to now your modal object's name.

```
  var dialog = registry.byId("modalDialogObjectName");
        var url = dialog.get("href");
        dialog.set("href", url);
```